# insert into table based un multiple joins / subqueries in mysql / mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have two tables, `meta_works(docID, tag, content)` and `meta_authors(authID, tag, content)`. Both tables have rows which include:

```
"xID", "authEng", "Author Name";
"xID", "authDate", "date range string";
"xID", "authLang", "language";
```

A distinct grouping in either table using the content from the tags of `authEng + authDate + authLang` will always have exactly one `meta_authors.authID` associated with it. One problem is I don't know how to do this distinct grouping across rows using multiple values of the same column.

I need to insert this distinct `authID` from `meta_authors` into `meta_works` for each distinct `meta_works.docID` as (`docID=meta_works.docID, tag="authID", content=meta_authors.authID`) so I can delete the other fields in `meta_works` and grab data from `meta_authors` instead.

The point of this attempted structure is to allow an arbitrary number of tags in either table associated with a work or author, and avoid duplicating the author data for each work, which helps with updating etc. The idea is to then expand this with a `meta_sections` table to allow meta tagging of work subsections as well.

I have tried to play around with inner/left/right joins and subqueries (never had to use these before due to limited mysql use) but cannot come up with anything that seems like even a start. The lack of examples is not for lack of trying/research, but with no experience this is proving difficult to approach. Perhaps it would be better to do this outside mysql and then update the table, but it intuitively feels well within the strengths of SQL so  i feel it is worth the question.

Comment: When you said docID=docID, did you mean its from a generated unique key?

Comment: No, it is not generated. It is almost always just the file name. But it needs to copy every distinct meta_works.docID into a new row and add this author tag and content to that row.

Comment: How do you determine which docID is corresponding to authors table then?

Comment: There are several thousand distinct docIDs. There are several hundred authors. Right now, the only way to know which author is to perform some sort of distinct grouping using `authEng + authDate + authLang`. All three of these are present for each docID, and when taken together they will always correspond to exactly one author in the meta_authors table. So to me it is easier to think that the docID does not correspond to the authors' table, but the authors in meta_authors correspond to the works they have written. continued =>

Comment: Try with INSERT+SELECT mw1.docID,'authID',ma1.authID FROM meta_works mw1,meta_works mw2,meta_works mw3,meta_authors ma1,meta_authors ma2,meta_authors ma3
WHERE 1=1
 AND mw1.docID=mw2.docID
 AND mw1.docID=mw3.docID
 AND ma1.authID=ma2.authID
 AND ma1.authID=ma3.authID
 AND mw1.tag='authEng'
 AND ma1.tag='authEng'
 AND mw2.tag='authDate'
 AND ma2.tag='authDate'
 AND mw3.tag='authLang'
 AND ma3.tag='authLang'
 AND mw1.content=ma1.content
 AND mw2.content=ma2.content
 AND mw3.content=ma3.content
;

Comment: I mean verify the output first, you might need to enhance do some distinct in SELECT

Comment: It works. I needed to use select distinct, probably because of dirty data. I did not know I could have multiple aliases for the same table. Feel free to make this an answer so I can mark as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Show some sample data, plus the desired output.